How would statute of limitations and virus spreading work?
For example, the ILOVEYOU worm and the creator, when the creator released the worm how would statute of limitations work if someone were to catch the worm today since the worm would still access someone's computer, wouldn't the creator be liable forever- or am I missing something?

Probably depends on what offence(s) might apply. If (whereever it might apply) there was an offence of writing a virus, that may have hit a time limit. If there was an offence of infecting a computer (and the original author can be liable... as opposed to whoever passed the virus on), then a new infection would, presumably, not be excluded.

There is immense variation between legal jurisdictions (countries and U.S. states) regarding how this is calculated, and it also depends upon the legal theory involved. Criminal statutes of limitations are calculated differently that civil ones and the statute of limitations in both criminal and civil cases also depends upon the particular charge or legal theory asserted.

If you left a bomb somewhere to be found and it killed someone in 20 years do you think you would be guilty of murder?
